# Java Outputstream - Side channel data leakage

Tags: java, outputstream, checkmarx

We have scanned our Java project using checkmarx to eliminate the security vulnerabilities in our project and we have got a scenario with the error "Side channel data leakage", below is the exact error message we are getting:

> Method replaceSpecialCharactersInString at line 304 of
> ProjectName/src/com/abc/dnu/main/DNUFlow.java gets private data from
> element psPassword . This element’s value flows through the code and
> is sent or written outside of the device or to external media or to a
> log file in callSOAP at line 213 of
> ProjectName/src/com/abc/dnu/main/DNUFlow.java. This constitutes Side
> Channel Data Leakage.

**Edit :** We are having a utility method called **replaceSpecialCharactersInString** which replaces any special character from the string literal **psPassword**,  this value is being eventually being written to an output stream(through a SOAP XML request called **wrappedSOAPMessage**) from this code(on which we are getting this security violation from checkmarx):

```
requestStream.write(wrappedSOAPMessage.getBytes());
```

I understood the issue but the solution i'm not able to find out any. If anybody came across any such sceanrio, kindly suggest what needs to be done here.

Comment: If you understand the issue please explain it. What does `replaceSpecialCharactersInString` have to do with `requestStream.write(wrappedSOAPMessage.getBytes())`?

Comment: @user207421 We are having a utility method called replaceSpecialCharactersInString which replaces any special character from the string literal psPassword, this value is being eventually being written to an output stream(through a SOAP XML request called wrappedSOAPMessage). I hope i'm able to explain the relation now
Have added this as an edit to the question.

Comment: Well then the action you are taking is deliberate, not an error, so you should either ignore this warning or configure it away.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are handling passwords Checkmarx flags this as an information leak unless it sees that you are using some form of encryption with any of the methods from libraries such as **javax.crypto.*** or **java.security.*** that will eventually encrypt the psPassword

This specific finding also is under the Java Android Checkmarx queries so I hope your project is an Android app (not tagged as such in the question)

Comment: @securecodingninja no, this is not an Android app, we have this project on Java.

Comment: @Kunal then get back to your security team and tell this vuln is not applicable and is a false positive